# bison rule match complex expression

Tags: regex, bison

I am trying to use bison rules to have the following expressions matched:

```
  ( (a1 > a3) && ((a2 <= 8) || (a1 == 4.5)) )
  ( ((b1 > b4) && (b2 <= 5.62)) || (b1 == 3) )
  (a < b)
  ( (c1 = 8.9) && (c2 > c1) )
```

I tried these rules but it had "conflicts: 6 shift/reduce, 6 reduce/reduce" and it does not work.

```
exprs:
'(' conditions ')'

conditions: conditions AND expression                                     
  | conditions OR expression
  | conditions AND condition
  | conditions OR condition
  | condition

condition: expression
  | expression AND expression
  | expression OR expression
  | '(' expression AND expression ')'                                        
  | '(' expression OR expression ')'

expression: '(' IDENTIFIER COMPARSION NAME ')'
  | IDENTIFIER COMPARISON NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at just three of your productions:

```
conditions: conditions AND expression                                     
          | conditions AND condition

condition: expression
```

Now suppose we have `conditions AND condition` at the top of the stack. We could now reduce using the third production, and then the first production. Or we could reduce using just the second production. In both cases, we end up with `conditions`:

```
conditions AND condition → conditions AND expression → conditions

conditions AND condition               →               conditions
```

So the grammar is ambiguous, which is what bison is telling you with the conflicts.

---

You don't show your flex file, but I'm puzzled by:

```
expression: IDENTIFIER COMPARISON NAME
```

What is the difference between `IDENTIFIER` and `NAME`? That seems like a confusion; it is quite possible that your scanner is not returning the tokens you expect it to be returning. You might want to use flex's debug feature (with `--debug`), which will print a message to stderr for every token matched.

---

The simplest way to write your grammar is:

```
expression: expression AND term
          | expression OR term
          | term
term      : comparison
          | '(' expression ')'
comparison: IDENTIFIER COMPARISON NAME
```

That gives `AND` and `OR` the same precedence, which is not usual. Normally, `OR` takes precedence over `AND`, so you could write, for example

```
a == 3 && b == 3 || a > 7 && b < 2
```

meaning

```
((a == 3) && (b == 3)) || ((a > 7) && (b < 2))
```

To achieve that, you just need another level of non-terminals:

```
expression: expression OR conjunct
          | conjunct
conjunct  : conjunct AND term
          | term
term      : comparison
          | '(' expression ')'
comparison: IDENTIFIER COMPARISON NAME
```

Comment: I left out that portion you were puzzled because there is no problem with that part, I have tested it.   Do you have correction rules to satisfy all these expressions ? The 3rd and 4th were very easy, but not the 1st and 2nd ones.

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by "it does not work", so I was throwing out a suggestion. I don't see how you can scan that correctly without a great deal of hackery, but apparently that is not the part which you claim is not working. In the future, please replace the phrase "it does not work" with a precise description of what happens, what you expected, and how they differ; we cannot see what is on the terminal in front of you, nor read your mind for your expectations. I'll provide the grammar fix in an edit.

Comment: Thank. I meant the 1st and 2nd ones had  problems.  I got a simple "1.1: syntax error".  Actually when I ran my code, I switched around the order and placed the 3rd and 4th before 1st and 2nd expressions.  So the results show me the 3rd and 4th work fine.  I used the options of "-d -t -v" for bison executable and it gave me the warning of "conflict: 6 reduce/reduce".

Comment: @user3658306: You should fix the reduce/reduce conflicts, although it is quite possible that bison has made the "correct" choice in resolving them.

Comment: Thanks. The first bison rules works for the first expression without any parentheses.  However the second bison rules do not work, I am learning how to debug it....  Another thing I do not understand , I assume '(' expression ')' was for getting the simple expression with the parentheses, such as (a == 9) working, but it does not.

Comment: @user3658306: If you use '(' to represent open paren in your bison file, you also need to return '(' in your scanner, usually with the pattern rule `.  { return yytext[0]; }`